# Bootstrap 3 Fixed Left Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am attempting to make a navbar that is fixed, fills col-md-3, and is positioned on the left. The fixed position is not an issue, however, the sizing is. If I leave the width declaration off, it reduces its width to the minimum it can. If I specify

```
width: inherit;
```

it takes up much more width than it should.

Is there a way to get the navbar to respect the col-md-3 width constraint and be fixed at the same time?

I have set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Miggl/ves2yvp5/

**Clarification:** The issue is that specifying the width on a fixed element is that is is in relation to the viewport, and not to the parent element. Is there a way to work around this using CSS in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Not in Bootstrap out of the box. You can use jQuery to get the width (which is fluid) and update on resize.

Comment: Yea, that's my last-ditch resort. :)

Comment: The problem is that setting it to the width of the `col-*-*` class will exceed the width by 30px (the left and right padding on the gutter). `col-*-3` is fluid so calculating that is not going to happen with CSS  since that's 25% - 30px = some percentage. Even CSS calc doesn't work

Comment: Right, I have implemented a successful jQuery solution for now, taking the width, subtracting padding and margin, etc. Using pure CSS may not be a viable solution at this time.